# Background image size not appearing correctly - CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I've been trying to insert a background image for a specific collection page on Shopify. I was able to edit the collection.liquid file, along with the main.ccs file that allowed the image to appear. I've done this in the past and the image has appeared just fine. I think the issue with the current image I am trying to upload is that it is horizontal. At the moment the image is being cut off and every single thing I have tried to edit the background-size has not worked at all. I just need for the image to fully appear on the screen.

Here is what is in the collection.liquid file:

```
   <style>
   body { background: url({{ 'slattzy-background-image.jpg' | asset_url }})
   </style>
```

And here is what is posted in the main.css file:

```
     .background-element {
       background-image: ({{ 'ssg-background-image.jpg' | asset_url }});
       background-size: 20px 20px;
       background-position: center; /* or 50% 50% */
       background-repeat: no-repeat;

      position: fixed;
      z-index: -1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try background-size: auto; or background-size: contain; or background-size: cover; depending on wether or not you want the image to stretch.
A background-size of 20px 20px will only display the top left most 20 by 20 pixel part of the original image.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: I just went ahead and replaced the background-size to those three different options. For some reason, it didn't make any changes at all. Do you know why it may be doing this?

Comment: Looking at the code in your question again, I noticed that you showed CSS code for 2 different elements (the body and the background-element) including 2 different urls for images. Make sure you are applying the styling to the correct DOM element. Is there anywhere in your HTML code an element with class="background-element"? If not you should either apply the styling of the background-element directly to the body. Or alternatively contain all your HTML code in a div with class="background-element".